# calculated column using date in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get an error when I try to use a user defined function in the calculated column. the expression in the calculated column looks like this:

```
(dbo.ufGetWaiterIDByTableID([DiningTable ID], [OrderDate]))
```

But when I change this expression to the following

```
(dbo.ufGetWaiterIDByTableID([DiningTable ID], '2016-05-10 21:30:15'))
```

it's fine and no error message.
Second parameter to my function is of datetime2 type and the [OrderDate] column is of datetime2(7) type too.
I can't sort out where the problem is.

The error is

```
Error validating formula
```

the definition of the function is

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufGetWaiterIDByTableID]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @tableID int, @adate datetime2(7)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @waiterID int

-- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
SELECT  @waiterID=tw.[Waiter ID]
FROM TableWaiter tw
WHERE tw.[DiningTable ID]=@tableID  AND DATEDIFF(d,tw.AssignDate, @adate)=
(Select min(DATEDIFF(d, AssignDate, @adate)) 
FROM TableWaiter 
WHERE [DiningTable ID]=@tableID AND DATEDIFF(d, AssignDate, @adate)>=0)

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @waiterID
```

Comment: well, what error do you get?

Comment: Where is the function definition?

Comment: Related to your question is that you are returning @waiterID without assigning a value to it.  Not related to your question is that `and AssignDate <= @adate` is logically equivalent to `DATEDIFF(d, AssignDate, @adate)>=0`, but will run faster.

Comment: I fixed it not by inserting formula into computed column in UI but using ALTER TABLE

Comment: Dan Bracuk, I am assigning a value to @waiterID in the Select clause